# Disable call key in Android when application is running in background

Tags: android, service, background, key, call

I would like to disable the green (call) key in my application and it should work even when my application is switched to background task and when Activity is paused. Should I use Android Service to disable the call key to achieve this ? If it is, then how to disable keys using Android Service. Please provide an insight on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use Android Service to disable the call key to achieve this ?

You cannot "disable" any keys.

When you activity is in the foreground, you may be able to "disable" some keys by intercepting them in `onKeyDown()` -- I forget if the CALL button can be handled this way or not.

But, if you do not have an activity in the foreground, you have no rights to interfere with the user experience this way.

Comment: @heavyinfo: Correct. In the background, you are not supposed to be able to control the keys.

Comment: I messed up the code inundation, so posting the comment again incase some one might need it.
Thanks for your reply . As you said, Iam able to block the call key when I run the application using,

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL) {
    return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
But when the application is not in the foreground, Iam unable to control the keys  as it is not allowed by Android.